# Fn Keys not working after Update on Ubuntu 14.04.3 - Rollback updates?

Tags: 14.04, updates, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've updated 2016-05-03 my Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my Asus Rog G75vw and I notice that fn keys stop working. I remember that all was fine before updates, so I decide rollback updates from that date.

I have a list of updates from that date:

- libssl1.0.0
- libssl1.0.0
- google-chrome-stable
- libgexiv2-2
- libpoppler-glib8
- libpoppler44
- libssl-dev
- libpoppler-qt4-4
- virtualbox-5.0
- libssl-doc
- paper-gtk-theme
- atom
- enpass
- openssl
- poppler-utils
- libtasn1-6

so, any gurú have idea if some of this packages maybe is causing me troubles with my fn keys? any idea how to fix? I'm thinking if I uninstall this packages...

This is the package I'm using for control fn keys on my laptop:

[nvidiabl-dkms_0.87_all](https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/tree/master/install/deb)

I've tried:

- reconfiguring keyboard: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` (makes no difference)
- I dont have F-lock key
- Changing input method on keyboard (only iBus and none) and nothing...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I also had [problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/849496/401249) with my fn keys with Ubuntu 16.04. I was able to figure out a solution thanks to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/55922/401249). Assuming that your problem is the same as mine, if you disable 'num lock' the keyboard starts to work properly again.

If this does not work for you, one workaround that used to help me was to plug and unplug a usb keyboard to my laptop and the laptop keyboard would go back to normal. However, once I restarted ubuntu, I had to do it again.

Hope this helps.