# keyboard fn keys enabled by default

Tags: unity, 16.04, keyboard, acer

I have been struggling with a keyboard problem recently and I didn't find a solution yet. When I login to my user account (standard user) my Fn keys are enabled by default, i.e. my typing outputs the Fn values instead of the corresponding key values (only for the keys that are associated with Fn values).

I can circumvent this issue: if I plug and unplug an external USB keyboard the problem disappears. Unfortunately it only lasts until the next login.

It is possibly worth mentioning that this only happens with my standard user account and not with my administrator account.

Has anyone encountered this problem and corresponding solution?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 (I can also reproduce this problem with elementary OS loki)
- Acer e11 aspire
- Unity Desktop