# Super key stuck on Ubuntu 18.04 - can't issue commands

Tags: keyboard

Today I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04. Everything seemed to work fine, I only had to redo some settings. One of these is that I remap some keys, e.g y to z and vice versa.

After a reboot the keyboard stopped working. I found out that the super key is stuck. Pressing `l`, for example, locks the screen. Unfortunately, `enter` is affected as well, making it impossible to c&p commands into terminal.

On top of that, there's a bug restricting visual keyboard to few apps only.

What can I do to unlock the super key? Might it be that changing the key mapping caused the issue?

Comment: Same issue here!

Comment: The issue might come from the Num Lock being turned on, pressing `Fn + ScrLk` fixes it. Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/55898/acting-as-though-the-laptop-fn-key-is-pressed

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this anymore since I downgraded again. But maybe @aIKid can test this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Get some canned air and try to blow any unwanted particles out of your keyboard. Sometimes a stuck key is just that. How did you change the key mapping? Please [edit] that info into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dirty hack, but remove your keyboard and restart your computer. Now plugin another keyboard, login and then you can check your mapping.