# How can I toggle function lock on boot?

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

I want to toggle my function lock when I boot.

I know the function lock can be toggled using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>
By default, my function lock is disabled on startup. So I have to manually toggle every time I boot up.
Is there a way to make it default on bootup?

EDIT: On Windows, by default function lock is enabled. But its the opposite in Ubuntu.

Comment: Related/duplicate?https://askubuntu.com/questions/55898/acting-as-though-the-laptop-fn-key-is-pressed https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key Will depend on your hardware.